# How to make named `params` arguments for methods?

Tags: c#, .net

C# has a great `params` keyword for passing arbitary number of arguments to functions such as `String.Format()`. But what if I need to pass named parameters (key-value pairs)? What is the best method for that (I'm looking for a short syntax on callers side)?

- `func(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "param1", val1 }, { "param2", val2 } }` is too cumbersome
- `func(param1 => val1, param2 => val2)` and `func(new { param1 = val1, param2 = val2 })` but it looks like language abuse and those features are not supposed to be used like that
- on `dynamic` objects I can parse optional parameters names `func(param1: val1, param2: val2)` which looks like a good solution but is doesn't work for common object methods

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic and common objects? The last option works fine for me.

Comment: I think the anonymous type part of your second option is fairly reasonable, to be honest. Maybe if you gave us more context we might be able to think of very different solutions though.

Comment: @piojo I mean that you don't specify argument names and count in the function declaration. Suppose that you want to make `String.Format()` function but name format parameters instead of using indices.

Answer (score 2):

you can create some overloads of function. when there are only 1 or 2 parameters on caller-side, those overloads will encapsulate usage of Dictionary

```
public void Foo (string paramA, object valueA)
{
   this.Foo(new Dictionary<string, object> { { paramA, valueA } });
}

public void Foo (string paramA, object valueA, string paramB, object valueB)
{
   this.Foo(new Dictionary<string, object> { { paramA, valueA },{ paramB, valueB } });
}

public void Foo (Dictionary<string, object> args)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If.NET Framework 4 is ok for you, maybe you can use [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.tuple.aspx)

```
void MyFunction(params Tuple<string, int>[] p)

// Example of call
MyFunction(Tuple.Create("pipo", 1), Tuple.Create("poil", 2)); // Matthew Mcveigh
```

**[Edit]**

An other way is to cast everybody as object:

```
void MyFunction(params object[] data)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 2)
    {
        var s = (string) (data[i]);
        var k = (int) (data[i+1]);

        ...
    }
}

...

// Example of call
MyFunction("pipo", 1, "poil", 2);
```

`params` can only be used once. And the type of the data passed by it is unique. With `params` you can either:

- Use the generic type `object`
- Use a tuple

There is no way that you can just pass an arbitrary long list of parameters with different type.

If you admit that, for preserving the type, you have to put your stuffs in some new *container* the cheapest way is to use two of them.

```
void MyFunction(string[] names, int[] values)

// Example of call
MyFunction(new[] {"pipo", "poil"}, new[] {1, 2});
```

Comment: But call will look like `func(new Tuple<string, object>("param1", val1), Tuple<string, object>("param2", val2))`. It looks worse than with dictionary.

Comment: @Poma it can be a little neater: `func(Tuple.Create("param1", val1), Tuple.Create("param2", val2))`

Answer (score 0):

One example of a library with an API like the one you want to make is iTween. It's well known in some game dev circles, so the practice can't be considered that bad.

It uses a helper function to create a hash table that's passed to the main function. You call it like this:

```
iTween.MoveTo(camera, iTween.Hash("path", iTweenPath.GetPath("CamPath"), "looktarget", player,
                                  "looktime", 0f, "speed", 2, "easetype", iTween.EaseType.linear));
```

It's open source, so you can look it if you want to search for "itween.cs". The helper function takes a `params object[] args` argument list, and makes sure each one is a valid type, then puts it in a Hashtable. Argument name (must be a string), then argument (in your case, this will be an object). The main function will access the arguments as elements of the Hashtable.

It's not type safe at all. But I think it's the only way to do what you're asking for.